# HOC React. How I Can recovery value wrapped in HOC component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Some one can help me, I'm using a HOC componente en React V6, The component is:

```
import React from "react";
import { SpinnerContainer, SpinnerOverlay } from "./with-spinner.styles";

const  WithSpinner = (WrappedComponent) =>{
    
return class extends React.PureComponent {
        
        render() {
            
            return false ? (
                <SpinnerOverlay>
                    <SpinnerContainer />
                </SpinnerOverlay>
            ) : (
                <WrappedComponent  />
            )
        }

    }

}
```

And I using this function:

```
 const CollectionOverviewWithSpinner = WithSpinner(CollectionsOverview);
 const CollectioPageWithSpinner = WithSpinner(CollectionPage);

<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={ <CollectionOverviewWithSpinner loading={loading}  />} />    
   <Route path="/:collectionId" element={ <CollectioPageWithSpinner loading={loading} />} />                 
</Routes>
```

My Question is, How I can recovery the value 'loading' en de HOC component???
I want to use this value here:

```
return loading ? (
        <SpinnerOverlay>
             <SpinnerContainer />
         </SpinnerOverlay>) 
              : 
          (
            <WrappedComponent  />
              )
```

Loading is a boolean value.

Comment: `this.props.loading ? ... : <WrappedComponent />`?

Answer (score 0):

I make the solution that give me @yousaf
and now it's working.

```
return this.props.loading ? (
                <SpinnerOverlay>
                    <SpinnerContainer />
                </SpinnerOverlay>
            ) : (
                <WrappedComponent  />
            )
```